# I've won the lottery. This is the second time this happened

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, tense-agreement, sequence-of-tenses

I suppose that the sentence:

> I've won the lottery. This is the second time this **happened**.

isn't correct - it must be:

> I've won the lottery. This is the second time this **has happened**.

But what is the reason for that?

Is it because the present tense in the beginning "This **is** the second time" determines the present perfect tense in the ending "this **has happened**"?

Or is it because we just have to use the present perfect in this context?

Comment: I'm not sure I can fully justify it as "invalid" on syntactic grounds, but I think your first example is at the very least "substandard / awkward". If you're going to use Simple Past ***happened*** rather than Present Perfect ***has happened***, I think it should be preceded by Simple Past *This **was** the second time...* But the example somewhat confuses the context by starting the entire utterance with Present Perfect ***I've [I have] won***

Comment: I suppose it's natural to use the present perfect if I'm telling my friend about winning the lottery. But I'm not sure about the correct tense for the verb happen in the second sentence. The usage of the present perfect is quite intricate. I don't want to imply recency and I don't mean any present result when I'm saying "this happened" - the message I want to convey is "the second time" - so what tense do I need to use for the verb happen?

Comment: It's not "unnatural" to use Present Perfect to tell your friend about winning the lottery, but in practice it's almost certainly less *likely* than Simple Past ***I won the lottery!*** as the *initial* utterance in a conversation. Whereas it might actually be *more* likely as a *response* - for example, if your friend had started the conversation by asking ***What are you looking so excited about**?* (because that initial utterance automatically puts the conversational focus on "present moment / time of utterance").

Answer (score 1):

This sentence

> "I won the lottery! This was the second time this happened."

is correct and more common than this one

> "I've won the lottery. This is the second time this has happened."

Comment: As a reminder, Stack Exchange answers are expected to *explain*, and not merely to *state*. Please [edit] the post to describe *why* it is correct, and demonstrate that it is more common.

Answer (score 0):

The correct sentence is:

> I've won the lottery. This is the second time this has happened.

Your use of the present perfect earlier in the sentence, in "I've won," indicates that the event has happened recently.  To be consistent with this, you have to use the present perfect in the second part of the sentence, as well.

See:

https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/present-perfect/